# Does Spring have support for SAP JCo transactions?

Tags: java, spring, jco

Does Spring have support for JCo transaction management? How can Transactions be combined with SAP's JCo or JRA transactions?

Regards

Answer (score 2):

Spring's aim was to ease programming complexities in the java world. As a JAVA programmer your wish is not surprising :)

Spring provides wrapper around standard specifications in JAVA like JTA, JDO, JDBC, etc. Whereas JCo is just a connector API provided by SAP to transact with SAP internal objects and interfaces. Currently, to my knowledge Spring does not provide any support for JCo.

JCo3 supports JCoContext for stateful connections, which is of little help but not to the extent what you may need.

You may actually need to implement *JCoServerTIDHandler* and one more interface from the same package (I don't exactly remember) for effective control over transaction management. Eventually, it will mean implementing Java Connector Architecture (JCA). This will be the right solution for your problem.

Hope, this helps.